# How to show all dataframe datatypes of too many columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe consists of 115 columns and I need to show the datatypes and null values using df.info(), but when using the code I got the following:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

RangeIndex: 25979 entries, 0 to 25978

Columns: 115 entries, id to BSA

dtypes: float64(96), int64(9), object(10)

memory usage: 22.8+ MB
```

is there a way to show all columns details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df is pandas dataframe

```
dataTypeSeries = df.dtypes
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#frequently-used-options), *"display.large_repr lets you select whether to display dataframes that exceed max_columns or max_rows as a truncated frame, or as a summary."*

So, you could try this:

```py
>>> pd.set_option("large_repr", "info")
>>> df
```